# jQuery Modal Window stuck open after displaying print dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made an example here, same problem on my site.
http://jsfiddle.net/WnsfD/

```
<a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-inverse btn-small" aria-hidden="true" onclick="printDiv('print')"><i class="icon-white icon-print"></i> Print</a>
```

This is the area I'm having trouble with.  (Just because it wouldn't let me post without some code)

I think this is pretty cut and dry here.  The javascript pops open the print dialog from the modal window, but once you print or cancel, the modal window is stuck open.  I have it set to close just like the Close button, because I noticed you couldn't close it afterwards, but the same effect.  I hate to have to refresh the page just to close the modal.

Note: Thanks to user [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/362043/kevin) for the print script.

Comment: Say goodbye to event handlers! Use a print style sheet.

Comment: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/aaaheatair/mU3MA/11/) is a modal box I created with 1.9 take a look and see if this will help you. you can click the mask or cancel button to close

Comment: Will it not do the same thing with a CSS print area?  I didn't think the problem lied in the JS.  I was thinking it was an issue with the print dialog popping up, ruining the modal's commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here I believe is that coping the HTML of an element to a variable only keeps the raw HTML, not the JS events and such. Therefore, when you put it back, you don't have the JS events anymore.

Using print style areas is likely the way to go. You leave the current elements alone so they don't lose their handlers.

I've forked an modified your fiddle, and it seems to work, although there's likely more CSS work you could do to make it better (like the text is light grey, you could force it to black)

http://jsfiddle.net/gAtMs/2/

Basically I created a new div for the print area which is empty (id="printme"). In the printDiv function, we copy the html to the printme div, then remove it after the print.

In the CSS for printing we hide everything under the div container, and the modal footer just cause we don't need the buttons on the printout.

We also hide printme in the css for regular screen displays, so the screen doesn't even change when you hit print.

The only reason to copy the HTML to the printme div is to make it easier to hide everything else all at once.

Here's the css...

```
#printme {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  .container {
    display: none;
  }
  .modal-footer {
    display: none;
  }

  #printme {
    display: block;
  }

}
```

Comment: I think this is the solution, I got it to work with the example modal on my site, however I can't get it to work with the existing one I'm using.  How can I modify this so that a div inside the modal body/content div will be the one printed?  Let's call it #printrequest.

Unfortunately there's so many working parts it's going to be very difficult to put the specific example here.  I've got everything structured the same way you've displayed here, but I still get content from my <body> (non modal stuff) showing up in the print dialog.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PZypj/ I have updated your example to more accurately reflect the setup of my divs.  It's relatively the same problem I'm having.  It only prints the selected area in my modal, however does not hide the body data on the page behind the modal.  (For some strange reason it _does_ hide my nav menu and footer.

Comment: Updated your update here... http://jsfiddle.net/PZypj/1/  Two minor issues, <div class="container"> became <div id="container"> in your new version, so I changed the css to #container to match, and that hide the container html from the printing. Then I moved the printme div back outside the container div, so it can be shown when the container div is hidden.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured I'd have to put the #printme div all the way outside everything.  I was hoping there was a more "elegant" solution so to speak, where I didn't have to disqualify everything I did not want to print, and only print the div with id="print".  Anyway thanks a lot FloatingCoder.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the same issue by just toggle the modal
take for instance this is the

```
$(document).on('click', '#buttonID', function(e){
     var printContents = document.getElementById("DivToPrintID").innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
     window.print();
     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
     $('#ModalID').modal('toggle');
});
```